# Is it possbile to have a SQL trigger for CRUD queries that gets an extra parameter from the query itself without using it for the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Triggers are new to me and I'm just wondering how can I fully benefit on using them.

Here are the two tables shelfs and shelfs_log:

```
CREATE TABLE `shelfs` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `shelf_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    `storage_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)

CREATE TABLE `shelfs_log` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `shelf_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    `storage_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

PHP function that gets executed when a new shelf is created to a storage: $shelf_name, $storage_id (and $user_id):

```
public static function createNewShelf($shelf_name, $storage_id)
    {
        global $conn;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id)
        VALUES ('$shelf_name', '$storage_id')";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $newShelf = array();

        if ($result) {
            $newShelf['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $newShelf['success'] = false;
        }

        return $newShelf;

        $conn->close();
    }
```

But I would like to have a trigger that keeps log of these inserts to a separete table but also having the user_id as an extra parameter that I could pass on these INSERT queries without writing the user_id to shelfs table.

Trigger would be something like:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `shelfs` 
AFTER INSERT ON `shelfs` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO shelfs_log (shelf_name, storage_id, user_id) 
    VALUES (NEW.shelf_name, NEW.storage_id, NEW.user_id)
```

A little hard me to explain and I couldn't find help for this matter on google.

Thanks in advance!

**Full solution for my problem was provided by the help of Akina. The extra parameters are added by using SET @paramater_name  := $parameter_value; in the original INSERT query and is run by using multi_query():**

```
$sql = "SET @user_id := $user_id; INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id) VALUES ('$shelf_name', '$storage_id');";

$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);
```

And after the trigger will pick up the extra parameter named @user_id:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `shelfs` 
AFTER INSERT ON `shelfs` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO shelfs_log (shelf_name, storage_id, user_id) 
    VALUES (NEW.shelf_name, NEW.storage_id, @user_id)
```

Comment: Moved my answer to the main question with propper format ^

Comment: I suppose the simplest solution would be to add the user id to the shelfs table?

Comment: Your table have no any unique key except the primary key, so your INSERT will insert the row unconditionally. In this case your trigger must produce correct result after fixing all misprints. https://dbfiddle.uk/ZUyExB99

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes that would be a easy way but it would break the logic when I would have also a trigger for the update queries. So I wouldnt be able to have a full history log anymore. Also I'm thinking of having one trigger that creates a row in a log_table having: user_id, action, table, current_date, etc.

Comment: @Akina your provide dbfiddle inserts  the user_id from thin air. The needed user_id I want to use comes from the normal shelfs_table insert. Cause I still dont know if what I'm asking is possible there is another way to aproach this problem, but it would need extra queries to do what I'm looking for. Sorry I have trouble explaining this ..

Comment: @Manny O_O ??? I don't understand your words... https://dbfiddle.uk/eqiQcCji

Comment: @Akina what's so complex here? the question is essentially "how to pass an *extra parameter* to a trigger" that is not related to the insert query. As far as I understand, it's just impossible. Right?

Comment: @YourCommonSense MySQL passes the whole row with all columns values to the trigger regardless the columns list specified in INSERT.

Comment: @Akina It's an *extra* parameter. That is NOT used in the query or related to it. Just a value in the program that executes the insert query. So anyway I suppose the answer is "no".

Comment: @YourCommonSense Easily. If you need to provide some extra data unrelated to the query into the trigger then you may simply set needed value(s) into user-defined variable(s) immediately before the query execution. These value(s) are available in the trigger if the variables set and the query execution is performed in the same connection.

Comment: The trigger picks up all the parameters from the basic query. But the needed user_id is not used on the shelfs_table, its only needed for the shelfs_log table. I understand that I can do this by having two separate queries but then I wouldnt have the power of triggers that I'm seeking! :D

Comment: Please, show me how I can pass the user_id without writing it to the first table if its possible. My sql knowledge is quite basic and looking for this answer on google took me nowhere.

Comment: Just like Akina said, use an SQL variable. That will require an extra query with SET statement. you can google it up. After setting an SQL variable you will be able to use it in the trigger as @user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please, show me how I can pass the user_id without writing it to the first table if its possible. – Manny

Extra data not passed into the query can be passed via user-defined variable:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `shelfs` 
AFTER INSERT ON `shelfs`
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO shelfs_log (shelf_name, storage_id, user_id) 
  VALUES (NEW.shelf_name, NEW.storage_id, @user_id);
```

Method 1. Assign the value before INSERT query.

```sql
-- set the variable
SET @user_id := '444';
-- now insert
INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id)
VALUES ('name 1', '11'),  ('name 2', '22');
```

Both queries must be executed in the same connection. Multiple rows with the same user_id can be inserted.

Method 2. Assign the value in the query using `INSERT .. SELECT`.

```sql
INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id)
SELECT 'name 3', '33'
FROM ( SELECT @user_id := 555) set_variable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'name 4', '44';
```

Multiple rows can be inserted using UNION ALL in SELECT. But all of them will use the same `user_id` value taken from the most last subquery (i.e. only one subquery should contain FROM clause, all other may not have it).

Method 3. Use inline assignment.

```sql
INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id)
VALUES ('name 5', CASE WHEN (@user_id := 666) IS NOT NULL THEN '55' END), 
       ('name 6', CASE WHEN (@user_id := 777) IS NOT NULL THEN '66' END);
```

Multiple rows with different `user_id` values can be inserted.

<kbd>[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QWOByT1Y)</kbd>

Comment: I used the method 1 and got the @user_id passed in the trigger! Thank you for explaining me how to achieve this! <3

Comment: @Manny Pay attention. Some connectors may hiddenly restore the connection if it is lost by some reason. If this loose-restore will occur between variable set and data insertion then you'll obtain incorrect result. I recommend you to execute both queries of method 1 in solid transaction - if the connection fails then the whole process will be rollbacked. Or the best way - execute them as a batch in single multi-query command.

Comment: I actually tried running the query in one $sql string but it always failed, so thats why I tried running the SET command and the main INSERT queries separeate. Also how can I SET multiple parameters? Funny that I cant seem to find an answer by searching "sql query SET multiple variable in one query"

Comment: @Manny *I actually tried running the query in one $sql string but it always failed* You use  `$conn->query` which does not support batches. Try `$conn->multi_query`.

Comment: So this is what I got now and it works like a charm:

$sql = "SET (at)user_id := $user_id, (at)test_id := 999;
        INSERT INTO shelfs (shelf_name, storage_id)
        VALUES ('$shelf_name', '$storage_id');";

$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);